# AWS Elemental MediaLive streaming latency issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming

I have created a medialive channel from this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/creating-channel-scratch.html

I have changed HSL output group with a segment length of 3 and number of segment 3 in Manifest and Segments section.

After changing segment length and number of the segment I am getting streaming latency around 20 to 30 seconds.

How I can reduce streaming latency  3 to 4 seconds?

Comment: I believe you're seeing delay in streaming compare to actual, I think the best configuration would be to have segment length of 6 seconds specified in Apple's official document here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices (Media Segmentation)

Comment: @JamesDean I have checked with segment length to 6 but I could not find any major different.

Comment: How much buffer is in the player?

Comment: I am testing on amazon Demo Player URL.

Comment: default buffer in amazon HSL demo player is 6 seconds

Comment: @szatmary default buffer is 6 in amazon HSL player

Answer (score 0):

There is a walkthrough on the AWS Media blog:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/part-4-how-to-compete-with-broadcast-latency-using-current-adaptive-bitrate-technologies/

Much of the latency is going to depend on the video player configuration. Typically, the player is set to buffer 3 segments so just in the player you are likely seeing 3s * 3 segments = 9s.

The other parts of the blog post (part 1) goes through how to measure where the latency is coming from.